# Two constructors

Tags: java, constructor

As I remember I can use first constuctor in second constuctor, but there is mistake on bold line, could you help me to correct it?

```
  public FaceExtAdditionCanvas() {
    profileImage.setSize(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT);
    add(profileImage, getWidth() / 2.0 - IMAGE_WIDTH / 2.0, IMAGE_MARGIN);
  }

  public FaceExtAdditionCanvas(GImage image){
    profileImage=image;
    **this.FaceExtAdditionCanvas();**
  }
```

Comment: Please review your Java syntax.

Comment: `this();` - all you need

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's, just as example:

```
public class Test
{
    public Test() {
        System.out.println("NO ARGS");
    }

    public Test(String s) {
        this();
        System.out.println("1 ARG");
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Test t = new Test("s");
    }
}
```

It will print

```
>>> NO ARGS
>>> 1 ARG
```

The correct way to call the constructor is by:

```
this();
```

Answer (score 4):

To call one constructor from another you need to use `this()` and you need to put it first.  In your case the default constructor needs to call the one which takes an argument, not the other ways around.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of a constructor is always an invocation to another constructor. You can choose between calling a constructor from the same class with "this(...)" or a constructor from the parent clas with "super(...)". If you don't include either, the compiler includes this line for you: super();